# Al cerrar ventan de alert con Bootstrap 4 no me salta el evento closed.bs.alert

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo implementada en Bootstrap 4 una pagina en la que me aparece un alert con un botón de cerrar. 
Si cierro el alert me desaparece correctamente pero no me lanza el evento closed.bs.alert para ejecutar otra función.

Este es el código para captar el evento:

```
<script>
    $('#miAlerta').on('closed.bs.alert', function () { alert('La alerta se ha cerrado'); });
</script>
```

Este es el código de mi alerta:

```
<div id="miAlerta" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Bienvenido!</h4>
    <p>Debes leer este importante mensaje para seguir.</p><hr />
    <p class="mb-0">Cuando lo necesites llamanos al teléfono: 555</p>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: El código que pones debería funcionar, es más, copié y pegué tu código en un [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moVogg) y funciona perfectamente, por ende, con certeza te digo, que tu problema esta en otro lado, edita la pregunta mostrando como cargas Bootstrap (y su versión..)

Comment: A mi no me funciona, al pulsar el boton hace se cierra la ventana haciendo el fadeout pero el evento no me salta. Voy a volverlo a revisar.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal gracias, no me llegaba el evento porque no había esperado a que la página cargara del todo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema, no había esperado a que la página se cargara del todo.

He agregado lo siguiente:

```
if (document.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('load', empezar, false); } else { window.attachEvent('onload', empezar); }

function empezar() {
    $('#miAlerta').on('closed.bs.alert', function () { alert('La alerta se ha cerrado'); });
}
```